# How to get a set of navteq links on a given road

Tags: sql, maps, postgis, here-api, navteq

I am using Nokia maps (Navteq, postgis DB).
Given a "link" I want to get all the "links" which belong to a bounding-box that map-match the same highway / route.

How can I do this using DB queries / Postgis?

Comment: I don't completely understand the question. What do you mean by map-match the same highway/route?

Comment: OK. I have some coordinates x,y which are at a highway or a route (not a city street). I want to find a set of links, let say 20Km ahead of the given point and 20Km before the given point. All the links must belong to the same route / highway.

Comment: How are the routes defined, with an id of some sort for underlying road segments. I am not familiar with Navteq data, but know Postgis well.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Road segments are represented by links. Each link has a starting node and an end node. For each link there is information about the name of the road.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this open topic. Do you know that HERE is meanwhile providing an online possibility for requesting linkIds within a boundingBox?

Further information can be sound here: Fleet Telematics Custom Locations

https://developer.here.com/documentation/custom-location/topics/key-concepts.html

And here is an example for a corridor search:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/custom-location/topics/example-search-corridor.html

That might be easier than host a database and then query the needed content. 
Hope this helps.